# Using "Base In" Correctly

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Does any native speakers object to "*base themselves*" being used on people?  A company could *base itself* in some city.  So, is it okay to say the Royal couple *based themselves* at some place?

Comment: From Macmillan Dictionary, **[base](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/base_34)** "if you are based somewhere, you have it as your main office or place of work, or the place where you live". -- I think it helps showing that *base* doesn't always have to be about offices or workplaces.

Comment: @DamkerngT. So, if, hypothetically speaking, I live in, say, San Diego, but commute to work in Los Angeles, would this sentence:  "*I am based in San Diego*"  be ambiguous?

Comment: @snailplane  It is very different.

Answer (score 1):

This can be used for both people and organizations.

See:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/based-in-vs-based-out-of

Comment: So, if, hypothetically speaking, I live in, say, San Diego, but commute to work in Los Angeles, would this sentence: "*I am based in San Diego*" be ambiguous?

Comment: Most people would assume that San Diego would be your home base or primary work location.